# How to combine 2 CMSampleBufferRef files?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to capture video using the AV foundation api's. I want to provide functionality to pause the video and restart it. I am trying figure out how to implement the pause feature will work. I was thinking about adding a button which will call the [session stopRunning] method. I would implement AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and capture CMSampleBufferRef each time the video is stopped. I then would like to combine all these into one file and then output it to the camera roll. Does this seem like the right approach?

OR

SHould i implement a pause button and capture video continuously and just throw away the frames when the user has the pause button clicked? If that was the case, then how would i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered your similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764779/how-do-i-pause-video-recording-with-iphone-sdk/5767266#5767266)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead i am looking into using AVAssetWriter instead of writing seperate vidoes and trying to merge them. Attempting the solution provided here @ [How do i pause video recording with iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764779/how-do-i-pause-video-recording-with-iphone-sdk/5767266#5767266)